# Is there a way to make IOS open deep link from default browser app?

Tags: ios, flutter, deep-linking

The last two days I have been struggling with one issue after another getting deep linking to work with node and flutter. After getting everything working I was confused as to why my links were still opening the website as opposed to the application.

Turns out that the problem seems to be with IOS and the options it gives to open the link. The image below shows those options. If I select the Safari option the browser opens the actual website, however to get the app to open I must select "Default browser app".

I mean I get that Apple seems to be giving options here but most users attempting to reset their passwords are not going to know this. I feel this is a horrible development issue.

- Am I missing something?
- Is there a way to stop this behavior?
- What are my options from those who have more experience with this?

[image]